# Issues with drawing to alternative RenderTarget2D, seems to draw to backbuffer

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

So in order to get the Color[] data from a texture after it has been rotated in order to use this data for perpixel collisions, I use the following method to draw said texture (rotated) to a separate RenderTarget2D, then convert this back into a texture2D and get the color data from it:

```
public Color[] GetColorDataOf(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Texture2D texture, float rotation)
    {
        // Get boundingBox of texture after rotation
        Rectangle boundingBox = GetEnclosingBoundingBox(texture, rotation);
        // Create new rendertarget of this size
        RenderTarget2D buffer = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, boundingBox.Width, boundingBox.Height); 

        // Change spritebatch to new rendertarget
        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(buffer);
        // Clear new rendertarget
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent);

        // Draw sprite to new rendertarget
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle(boundingBox.Width / 2, boundingBox.Height / 2, texture.Width, texture.Height), null, Color.White, rotation, new Vector2(boundingBox.Center.X, boundingBox.Center.Y), SpriteEffects.None, 1f);

        // Change rendertarget back to backbuffer
        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

        // Get color data from the rendertarger
        Color[] colorData = new Color[boundingBox.Width * boundingBox.Height];
        Texture2D bufferTexture = (Texture2D)buffer;
        bufferTexture.GetData(colorData);

        return colorData;
    }
```

Now I'm having two issues with that (I expect they are linked), firstly the texture gets drawn on screen, and all the Color[] data returned is empty (i.e all fields equal to 0).

** Edit **
Using Texture2D.SaveAsPng() I can see that bufferTexture is the correct size but just completely transparent indicating that the issue would lie in drawing to the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed it. Turns out I need to create another set of SpriteBatch.Begin() and SpriteBatch.End() calls around where I drew to the new rendertargets, otherwise it was just drawing to the backbuffer instead.